Undefined references to SDL symbols?
I am trying to create a project in the C89 language using the SDL2 library:
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        printf("SDL initialization error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a window
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "SDL2 Window",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        640, 480,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
    );

    if (window == NULL) {
        printf("Window creation error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    // Event handling
    SDL_Event event;
    int running = 1;
    while (running) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = 0;
            }
        }
        SDL_Delay(16);  // To limit CPU usage
    }

    // Clean up and close SDL
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}

...but am getting errors during linking:
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o Test.o "..\\Test.c" 
gcc -o Test.exe Test.o 
Test.o: In function `SDL_main':
C:\Users\SiRecognizer\OneDrive\eclipse-workspace\Test\Debug/../Test.c:6: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
C:\Users\SiRecognizer\OneDrive\eclipse-workspace\Test\Debug/../Test.c:7: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
C:\Users\SiRecognizer\OneDrive\eclipse-workspace\Test\Debug/../Test.c:12: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
C:\Users\SiRecognizer\OneDrive\eclipse-workspace\Test\Debug/../Test.c:20: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
C:\Users\SiRecognizer\OneDrive\eclipse-workspace\Test\Debug/../Test.c:21: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
C:\Users\SiRecognizer\OneDrive\eclipse-workspace\Test\Debug/../Test.c:29: undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
C:\Users\SiRecognizer\OneDrive\eclipse-workspace\Test\Debug/../Test.c:34: undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
C:\Users\SiRecognizer\OneDrive\eclipse-workspace\Test\Debug/../Test.c:38: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
C:\Users\SiRecognizer\OneDrive\eclipse-workspace\Test\Debug/../Test.c:39: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

16:23:59 Build Failed. 10 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.776ms)

Could you help me resolve this issue?
I am using MinGW and have verified the correct installation of SDL2 using the 64-bit version.

I'm not seeing the -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 flags. What tutorial are you following? Also GCC 6 is quite outdated (latest is 14), I recommend installing the latest one from MSYS2.

Welcome to SO. Why would you intentionally use something as C89? That's already outdated since a few decades. You should at least use C99.

@HolyBlackCat Should we mark this as a dup of your answer: How do I use SDL2 in my programs correctly??

@CraigEstey I guess. Added my dupe vote.
